# Does wake up club only have a super short alarm?

Tags: wake-up-club

I've been trying to use Wake Up Club, the first day went alright but since then the alarm seems to only ring for ten seconds or less before saying it's too late. It's totally unusable at that point. Is this because I have a bad group or something or is there a way to change the timer or what?

Comment: Reminds me of this http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have discovered Wake Up Club's secrets; if you leave the Vita on Standby on Wake Up Club, you will get the "wake up game" when the alarm is going off (the game does explicitly tell you to leave the game on standby).

However, if you don't leave wake up club on, the alarm will still go off, but when you try and deactivate the alarm it will simply say that your time's up, rather than give you the minigame. Despite it saying "time is up" it doesn't count against your Wake Up Club streak if the alarm goes off but doesn't let you play the game. I assume your streak will only be broken if you fail to wake up when the game is left on standby properly, allowing the game to actually be played.